# JMSSerializerBundleThe Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString()"

Tags: json, serialization, symfony, bundle

I've got a problem with JMSSerializerBundle.

I have my entity AGVote there :

```
<?php

namespace K\AGBundle\Entity;

use JMS\SerializerBundle\Annotation\Type;
use JMS\SerializerBundle\Annotation\Accessor;
use JMS\SerializerBundle\Annotation\AccessType;
use JMS\SerializerBundle\Annotation\Exclude;
use JMS\SerializerBundle\Annotation\ExclusionPolicy;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


/**
 * K\AGBundle\Entity\AGVote
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * 
 */


/*
 * 
/** @AccessType("public_method") */

class AGVote
{


   /**
* @Type("integer") 
* @Accessor(getter="getId") 
*/

 /**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
public $id;

 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text")
  * @Accessor(getter="getQuestion")
  * @Type("text")
 */
public $question;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="smallint")
 * @Type("integer")
 * @Accessor(getter="getActif")
 */
public $actif;

 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\K\KBundle\Entity\Users", cascade={"all"})
  * @Exclude
 */
protected $users;



/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set question
 * Nb : Only AG admin can set a question
 * @param text $question
 */
public function setQuestion($question)
{
    $this->question = $question;
}

/**
 * Get question
 *
 * @return text 
 */
public function getquestion()
{
    return $this->question;
}

/**
 * Set actif
 *
 * @param smallint $actif
 */
public function setActif($actif)
{
    $this->actif = $actif;
}

/**
 * Get actif
 *
 * @return smallint
 */
public function getActif()
{
    return $this->actif;
}

 /**
 * Set Users
 *
 * @param K\KBundle\Entity\Province $Users
 */
public function setUsers(\K\KBundle\Entity\Users $users)
{
    $this->users = $users;
}

/**
 * Get Users
 *
 * @return K\KBundle\Entity\Users
 */
public function getUsers()
{
    return $this->users;
}

  public function __toString()
{
   return $this->getquestion();
}

}
```

I have made a controller that juste return me an AGVote Entity in Json :

```
   public function jsonvoteAction($id) {
  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
  $entity = $em->getRepository('KAGBundle:AGVote')->findOneById($id);

  if ($entity->getActif() == 1) {
     $serializer = $this->container->get('serializer');
     $serializer->serialize($entity, 'json');
     $response = new Response($serializer);

     return $reponse;
     }
     }
```

I have a response in Json but it is a error saying :

> [{"message":"The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), \"object\" given.","class":"UnexpectedValueException","trace":

In fact I have already implement a __toString() method inside of all my entities.

Does anyone have an idea ?

Thanks you :)

Comment: Please, next time, take some time to properly format your code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you call the `serialize` method on the `$serializer`, it returns the serialized data (a string).
The problem is that you do not use this returned value, and create the response with the `$serializer` itself, which makes no sense.

First, store the serialized $entity:

```
$serializedEntity = $serializer->serialize($entity, 'json');
```

Then, you can return a new response using with string:

```
return new Response($serializedEntity, 200, array('Content-Type' => 'application/json'));
```

Comment: This work, but it is the classic way that don't fit with my needs.
In fact it just display the data of the entity, ({"id":89,"question":"dg","actif":1} ) but not a reference to my entity like :'MyNamespace\MyObject'
I was thinking that the JMSSerializerBundle should give me that ?

Comment: The output you just quoted, is exactly what the JMSSerializerBundle is supposed to output. Write the full response you expected

Comment: Ok ! Someone told me that it should do this :P
Thanks you that's clear now ! 
I will do it by myself, misunderstanding is always my worst enemy :D

Comment: Serializer does not use yml config in this case where I have set expose rules for fields.